# How to access a specific Button in a View in Drawer ListView

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer like this
[image: Screensot]

Now I want to access the Test Button inside the ListItem 1
I tried it inside the DrawerLayout.onItemClickListener() but it is not working.

I have my drawerListener() as a ActionBarToggle object.

How can I get access to the button?

Help Needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution.
I made a class implementing OnClickListener and set the onclick method of the button inside the getView of the listview.